# How can I change the Bootstrap 4 range slider colors?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

[image]

Is there any ideas how to customize bootstrap 4 ranges colors and change blue thumb color to 'gray'?

Input html below.

```
<p id="slider" class="range-field">
  <input 
    type: "range",
    min:"0" max:"3"
    class: "custom-range"
    value: "2"
    disabled: "true"
  />
</p>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try the following code - various vendor-specific classes, use depending on your requirement needs:

```
.custom-range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background: gray;
}

.custom-range::-moz-range-thumb {
  background: gray;
}

.custom-range::-ms-thumb {
  background: gray;
}
```

Per comments by [Astariul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9494790/astariul) and [aliawadh980](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3172517/aliawadh980), change the shadow that occurs when the thumb is clicked like this:

```
-webkit-slider-thumb:active {
    background-color: red;
}
-webkit-slider-thumb,
.custom-range:focus::-webkit-slider-thumb, 
.custom-range:focus::-moz-range-thumb,
.custom-range:focus::-ms-thumb {
    box-shadow: red;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. This guide works good for Bootstrap too: [How to Style Input Type Range in Chrome, Firefox, and IE](https://brennaobrien.com/blog/2014/05/style-input-type-range-in-every-browser.html).
2. You can open [bootstrap.css](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.css) from the latest version, search for "range" and use the code you find as a sample:

```css
.form-range {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1.5rem;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
.form-range:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
.form-range:focus::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #fff, 0 0 0 0.25rem rgba(13, 110, 253, 0.25);
}
.form-range:focus::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #fff, 0 0 0 0.25rem rgba(13, 110, 253, 0.25);
}
.form-range::-moz-focus-outer {
  border: 0;
}
.form-range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  margin-top: -0.25rem;
  background-color: #0d6efd;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
  .form-range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-transition: none;
    transition: none;
  }
}
.form-range::-webkit-slider-thumb:active {
  background-color: #b6d4fe;
}
.form-range::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.5rem;
  color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #dee2e6;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}
.form-range::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  background-color: #0d6efd;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
  .form-range::-moz-range-thumb {
    -moz-transition: none;
    transition: none;
  }
}
.form-range::-moz-range-thumb:active {
  background-color: #b6d4fe;
}
.form-range::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.5rem;
  color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #dee2e6;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}
.form-range:disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.form-range:disabled::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background-color: #adb5bd;
}
.form-range:disabled::-moz-range-thumb {
  background-color: #adb5bd;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **Sass** you have to change (overwrite) value of `$custom-control-indicator-checked-bg` variable from [_variables.scss](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/319de5b309561146d1d5803b553379591d890411/scss/_variables.scss#L541).

Default value of `$custom-control-indicator-checked-bg` is:

```
$component-active-bg: theme-color("primary") !default;
// ...
$custom-checkbox-indicator-indeterminate-bg: $component-active-bg !default;
```

Comment: How is it possible to change it? And how to change it many times? I have many sliders in one single page and need to make them in different colors. I have a single main scss file, should I @import the _variable.scss to override the !default values? I used $custom-checkbox-indicator-indeterminate-bg: #000; or $custom-checkbox-indicator-indeterminate-bg: #000 !default; in my main scss file but it didn't work.