# Change Bootstrap range slider color to Hex color?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm looking to change the default blue color of a Bootstrap range slider, but I'm not sure if that's possible. Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rfuqmnh9/2/) of what I have so far. Ideally I'd like to change this to a Hex color, like red. Can this be done with something simple like CSS?

Here is my html code:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!--  Age Range Slider  -->
    <div class="col">
      <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 21rem;">
        <div class="card-body text-center">
          <div class="d-flex flex-column">
            <label for="age_slider" class="form-label"> Age</label>
            <input class="slider" name="age_slider" id="age_slider" type="range" value="30" max="100" min="1" oninput="this.nextElementSibling.value = this.value">
            <output>30</output>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I've been flagged as having a similar question to the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56424105/how-can-i-change-the-bootstrap-4-range-slider-colors), but the answer provided in that question is not working for me either.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this properties:

```
.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100;
  margin: 50px auto;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: visible;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

but they are not too functional

Comment: So this is super helpful, but one of the things I like about the default slider is that the blue part only fills in to the left of the slider, as opposed to the entire length of the slider. Is this still possible, just with a color other than the default blue?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome

```
.slider::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background-color: #333333;
}
```

Firefox

```
.slider::-moz-range-track {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  background-color: #333333;
}
```

Comment: So this is helpful, but one of the things I like about the default slider is that the blue part only fills in to the left of the slider, as opposed to the entire length of the slider. Is this still possible, just with a color other than the default blue?

Comment: Firefox
`.slider::-moz-range-progress { background-color: #ebebeb; }`

Chrome
`.slider {  -webkit-appearance: none;  }`

Comment: but for chrome, need to create `<div class="slider-wrapper">` and style it

Comment: So for Chrome how do I style it?